# How to solve this multi-integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate this in a better way ?

$\iiint _ { \Omega } ( x + y + z ) ^ { 2 } dxdydz$

$\Omega  = \left\{ \begin{array} { l } { x ^ { 2 } + y ^ { 2 } \leq 2 a z } \\ { x ^ { 2 } + y ^ { 2 } + z ^ { 2 } \leq 3 a ^ { 2 } } \end{array} \right.$

Comment: Use spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before converting to spherical coordinates, notice two things. One, $(x+y+z)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xy + 2xz + 2yz$. Second, the region of integration $\Omega$ has symmetry across both the planes $x=0$ and $y=0$. The last three terms in the integrand are odd functions of $x$, $y$, or both, so we have

$$\int_\Omega x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xy + 2xz + 2yz \hspace{4 pt}dV = \int_\Omega x^2 + y^2 + z^2 dV$$

Lastly, when you convert to spherical (or cylindrical) coordinates, do not do the radial coordinate first. Integrate the polar angle first, it will make life a lot easier.

---

$\mathbf{\text{EDIT}}$: On second thought, the easiest way to do this integral would probably be in cylindrical coordinates, with $\rho$ first like so:

$$2\pi\left( \int_0^a \int_0^{\sqrt{2az}} \rho^3 + \rho z^2 d\rho dz + \int_a^{\sqrt{3}a} \int_0^{\sqrt{3a^2-z^2}} \rho^3 + \rho z^2 d\rho dz\right)$$

The intuition being, the integrand is filled with odd powers of $\rho$, so the square roots will cancel out after they are integrated once. This takes around the same amount of time as the method I suggested above because while everything simplifies down to a polynomial, there are many terms.

The first method of integrating $\theta$ first in spherical coordinates will have very few terms, but a $u$ substitution and some algebra for the final step.